# Where is "tidy" located in "twill"?

Tags: module, tidy, twill

on **["twill" documentation page](http://twill.idyll.org/browsing.html)** it is written:

---

> By default, **twill** will run pages
>   through **tidy** before processing
>   them. This is on by default because
>   the **Python** libraries that parse
>   **HTML** are very bad at dealing with incorrect **HTML**, and will often
>   return incorrect results on "real
>   world" Web pages. To disable this
>   feature, set **config do_run_tidy 0**

---

But where is this **tidy** program located inside **twill**? I have downloaded "**twill 0.9**" and [**looked into "twill" folder contents**](http://roundcan.narod.ru/some_pages/twills_contents.html) - I just can't find there such a file (or a module) that would be named "**tidy**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

twill uses the commandline version of tidy if installed on your system. the method that calls tidy to clean your code is located in the utils.py and named '`run_tidy`'. its called by the command '`tidy_ok`' which is defined in commands.py

if **use_tidy** is set to true (which it is by default) the `_cleanup_html` method in **ConfigurableParsingFactory** calls the `run_tidy` method